# Sure Thing Arbitrage

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

> Consider the following model with **assets** $S_1, S_2$ and **three states**, and suppose that $r = 10\%$
>   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> n&S_n(0)& S_n(1,\omega_1) & S_n(1,\omega_2) & S_n(1,\omega_3) \\ \hline
>  1&4 & 5&6 &3\\ \hline
>  2&11 &12 & 9&7\\ \hline
> \end{array}
>
> For clarity, time 1 means one year.
>
> **Show that there is a sure-thing
>   arbitrage.**

So, what I have done is I tried to find risk-neutral probabilities and I got $\Bbb Q = (\frac{10}{11},\frac{-3}{11},\frac{4}{11})$ which has a negative probability so a risk-neutral probability measure does not exist which means we may not be able to replicate the claims. But I am not quite sure how to construct a portfolio for this question.

A friend suggested a portfolio consisting of 11 units of asset 1 and 4 units of asset 2 and then clearly there is arbitrage between the 2. I am just not quite sure about the reasoning for this.

> Note, a portfolio $H$ is a **sure-thing arbitrage** if value $V_0(H) = 0$ and, for every ω ∈ Ω, $V_T (H, ω) > 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a long position of $11$ units of $A_1$ and a short position of $4$ units of $A_2$.  That costs $0$ initially.  Verify that this portfolio has positive value in each of the three scenarios.

Note:  it is not clear to me whether or not you are meant to take the cost of the borrow into account.  Since rates are $10\%$, whoever loaned you $A_1$ should get a $10\%$ return on the proceeds from the short sale.  That comes to $4.4$ here and one can verify that, even with this cost, the position is still a perfect arbitrage.  The only close one is the third scenario and in that the portfolio is worth $33-28=5>4.4$.

Comment: I guess this is the part that I dont quite understand. When you go long on 11 units of $A_1$ and short 4 units of $A_2$ do we not "lose" the $A_2$ from the portfolio? I thought of long as something remaining in the portfolio and short as something leaving the portfolio. But I guess that is wrong. I suppose at time 1 I should find that for state $\omega_1$ the value of the portfolio is $11*5-4*12>0$. Could you clarify how I should think of the portfolio and long and short positions on assets in the portfolio?

Comment: To go short an asset means that you have sold an asset you do not posses. Here, we short the asset in the first period and make delivery in the second.  If the asset has dropped in price over the period, we make money.  If the price has gone up  we lose money.

Comment: Note:  it is not clear to me whether or not you are meant to take the cost of the borrow into account.  Since rates are $10\%$, whoever loaned you $A_1$ should get a $10\%$ return on the proceeds from the short sale.  That comes to $4.4$ here and you can verify that, even with this cost, the position is still a perfect arbitrage.

Comment: So taking a position at time 0 kind of means locking in what we will do with the asset at time 1?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  Do you understand my comment on the cost of the borrow?

Comment: The sale of the short would give $0.1*11*4 $ to the person who lent you asset $A_1$. Correct?

Comment: Yes.  The person who held $A_1$ seeks to get the riskless return on their asset.  In real life, borrowing stocks for short sales can be a tricky business.

Comment: I think I understand this much better now. Thank you!