# Risk-neutral probability measures

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

> Consider a market with  $\Omega= (\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3)$, $r = 0$ and one asset $S$.
>
> Suppose that $S(0) = 2$ and $S$ has claim $\bar S = (1, 3, 3)$ at time 1.
>
> Find all the risk-neutral probability measures on $\Omega$

What I did for this question is construct a similar table as in [Sure Thing Arbitrage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092153/sure-thing-arbitrage). I got a system of solutions which gave

$\Bbb Q=(\frac{1}{2}, p, \frac{1}{2}-p)$ as the set of all possible risk neutral probability measures. But again, I am not sure if I can take the claims at time 1 to be the same at the price/value of the asset at time 1.

Comment: A claim represents the payoff of the asset in each state of the world; in this case, the claim tells you how much you will earn given three possible outcomes. Economically speaking, the asset can be thought of a bond that pays well in two states (where the claim is 3) and pays badly in one state (where the claim in 1). Then, you can construct the risk-neutral probabilities by solving the following system of equations.

Comment: So is my thinking for the question correct? As in, I can take the claim for each state to be the value of the asset at that time in that state?

Comment: I think so; however, when you calculate the simultaneous equations system that is, x+3y+3z=1 and x+y+z=1, you get that x=0.5 and y=0.5-z. So, you will end up with multiple risk-neutral probabilities as y+z=0.5 and so you have that: 0<y<0.5, 0<z<0.5 and y+z=0.5. In fact, let's assume that you choose arbitrarily that y=1/8 and z=3/8 (which satisfies the conditions), then you still have valid risk-neutral probability measures. Multiple risk-neutral probabilities mean incomplete markets.